# Prevent closing InAppBrowser - Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I have an simple app that `onDeviceReady` starts the InAppBrowser and shows a website. Then The InappBrowser will be closed when a specific event occurs.

As you may know, on Android platform pressing "back button" closes the InAppBrowser which I want to be prevented. I want to InAppBrowser be shown to user until that event occurs and user be unable to close the InAppBrowser.

Be noted that I am not talking about `hardwareback` options. `hardwareback` is a useful option which lets user goes back in history of his/her navigation by pressing "back button" but at the first page (when there is nothing left in history), it closes InAppBrowser while I want InAppBrowser still remains open.

Comment: that's how the plugin works, if you want it to do a different thing you'll have to edit the source code. Anyway, you shouldn't create apps that just open a website

Comment: it is just an advertise, it closes after couple of seconds when a trigger fires (I mentioned the trigger in question).

Comment: @jcesarmobile, anyway I looked up the code and it was in Java and I am not familiar with Java, any other work around have you in mind beside source code modification. like custom event listener override?

Comment: No, there is no other way, inAppBrowser can be closed with back button, the only way to prevent this is to change the source code

Answer (score 3):

In the latest InAppBrowser versions you still have to change the `onBackPressed` function in the JAVA code of `InAppBrowserDialog.java` plugin code:

```
public void onBackPressed () {
    if (this.inAppBrowser == null) {
        this.dismiss();
    } else {
        // better to go through the in inAppBrowser
        // because it does a clean up
        if (this.inAppBrowser.hardwareBack() && this.inAppBrowser.canGoBack()) {
            this.inAppBrowser.goBack();
        }  else {
            // this.inAppBrowser.closeDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like this approach I have asked a feature on GitHub; you can follow it on GitHub here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/530

Comment: i tried that solution but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is fairly old but I stumbled upon it when I was searching for the answer myself.

You can edit the InAppBrowserDialog.java file (plugins>cordova-plugin-inappbrowser>src>android) to change the behavior of the back button once it's pressed.

```
this.inAppBrowser.closeDialog()
```

Comment out the above piece of code in the onBackPressed() method, and this will prevent the browser from being closed on hardware back, while still maintaining the navigation functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no solution available to prevent the inappbrowser from closing when the hardware back button is pressed. The only thing you can do is reload the same URL in the inappbrowser again after a minimum delay of 500ms. The delay is important, otherwise, the inappbrowser window won't be shown.